# Python / Pandas: Dataframe subset by filter criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have the following dataframe which is list of races and results.

```
      Date       R   #   Fin  Win
0     11182017   1   1   2     0 
1     11182017   1   2   1     5   
2     11182017   1   3   3     0   
3     11182017   2   1   2     0   
4     11182017   2   2   1     10   
5     11182017   3   1   1     6    
6     11182017   3   2   2     0
```

I want to only return the races (all entrants not just the row with 10) where the Win column is greater than or equal to 10. Example below

```
      Date       R   #   Fin  Win
3     11182017   2   1   2     0   
4     11182017   2   2   1     10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `filter`

```
df.groupby(['Date','R']).filter(lambda x : (x['Win']>=10).any())
Out[568]: 
       Date  R  #  Fin  Win
3  11182017  2  1    2    0
4  11182017  2  2    1   10
```

Another solution by using `transform`

```
df[df.groupby(['Date','R']).Win.transform(lambda x : (x>=10).any())]
Out[573]: 
       Date  R  #  Fin  Win
3  11182017  2  1    2    0
4  11182017  2  2    1   10
```

Comment: Wen, TY for the quick response...can you possibly explain the mechanics of the  code? df.groupby(['Date','R']).filter(lambda x : (x['Win']>=10).any())

Comment: @Derek it group by Date and R , find any value no less that 10 for all Win within the group, if any of them match , keep all , else drop it

Comment: @Derek if this is what you need , can you consider accept it ?