# Python/Pandas: subset a Dataframe by matched index criteria

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by

I am new to Python (used to coding with cousin R) and am still getting a hang of pandas.  There is an [incredibly helpful, related post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409682/python-pandas-dataframe-subset-by-filter-criteria), but instead of filter()ing by a set number, I was hoping to do so by a criteria defined in a second data set.

Let's make some toy data:

```
import pandas as pd

pets = [['foxhound', 'dog', 20], ['husky', 'dog', 25], ['GSD', 'dog', 24],['Labrador', 'dog', 23],['Persian', 'cat', 7],['Siamese', 'cat', 6],['Tabby', 'cat', 5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(pets , columns = ['breed', 'species','height']).set_index('breed')

TooBigForManhattan = [['dog', 22],['cat', 6]]

TooBig = pd.DataFrame(TooBigForManhattan, columns = ['species','height']).set_index('species')
```

I am trying to subset `df()` by selecting the breeds that are less than or equal to the `TooBig()` values.  My pseudo-code looks like:

```
df.groupby(['breed','species']).filter(lambda x : (x['height']<='TooBig Cutoff by Species').any())
```

The data I am working with are thousands of entries with about a hundred criteria, so any help in defining a solution that could work at that scale would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a join on a single column you can `map` each species to its height and check whether the value in the DataFrame is smaller.

```
df[df['height'] <= df['species'].map(dict(TooBigForManhattan))]

         species  height
breed                   
foxhound     dog      20
Siamese      cat       6
Tabby        cat       5
```

---

Here's a bit more detail about some of the intermediate steps.

```
# List of lists becomes this dict
dict(TooBigForManhattan)
#{'cat': 6, 'dog': 22}

# We use this Boolean Series to slice the DataFrame
df.height <= df.species.map(dict(TooBigForManhattan))
#breed
#foxhound     True
#husky       False
#GSD         False
#Labrador    False
#Persian     False
#Siamese      True
#Tabby        True
#dtype: bool
```

Comment: Nice one, just incase the mapper is a 1 column df , `df[df['height'] <= df['species'].map(TooBig.squeeze())]`

Comment: Big thanks for showing the steps.  I am getting a KeyError on my actual data using `df[df['height'] <= df['species'].map(dict(TooBigForManhattan))]`, but running through the intermediate steps, I get a clean Boolean output.  How can I go from the big df() with True and False to the final output?

Comment: @EBITDAN hmm, print `df.columns` and make sure `height` and `species` are in there. Did you perhaps try the other solution and merge that way your columns got messed up?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with which you can use [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
out = (df.merge(TooBig,left_on='species',right_index=True,suffixes=('','_y'))
         .query("height<=height_y").loc[:,df.columns])
print(out)
```

Or similarly:

```
out = df.merge(TooBig,left_on='species',right_index=True,suffixes=('','_y'))
out = out[out['height']<=out['height_y']].reindex(columns=df.columns)
print(out)
```

---

```
         species  height
breed                   
foxhound     dog      20
Siamese      cat       6
Tabby        cat       5
```